# CORS or Something Else - AngularJS and Ionic

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, cors

I am working on an Ionic app and I can't seem to find where the breakdown is for this particular problem. I am trying to serve a single user from the User model and I get a "GET http://localhost:3000/api/users/5743a5f9db9e7ce607d47c9c 403 (Forbidden)". That long number on the end of the link there is the user id. Is this a CORS issue or something else? Here's my code:

from the Global Controller:

```
.controller('GlobalCtrl', function(Users, $rootScope, $state, $stateParams, $window, Stocks, $scope){
    if ($state.current.name == 'show-user') {
    console.log("state first time",$state.current.name)
    Users.show($stateParams.userID).success(function(results){
      console.log("state second time",$state.current.name)
      //console.log("GlobalCtrl single user results", results)
      $scope.user = results
      console.log("$scope.user", $scope.user)
    })
  }
})
```

from the User Service:

```
 .factory('Users', function($http) {
  var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:3000/api/users/'

    return {

      index: function(){
        return $http.get(apiUrl)
      },

     show: function(userID){
       console.log("user service get running", userID);
       return $http.get(apiUrl + userID)
       console.log("userID:",userID)
     }
  }
})
```

The states are standard. userID is identified in the index all users template in the ui-sref as follows:

```
<a ui-sref="show-user({userID: user._id})">{{user._id}}</a>
```

Thanks so much for your help! If more info is needed let me know.

Comment: 403 is generally returned for an unauthorized action (e.g. trying to access a resource you don't have authorization for or trying to list a directory's content).  What's server side framework are you using?

Comment: Hi Dustin! Thanks for your reply. It's a MEAN stack app so using NodeJS and ExpressJS. Could it be because the back end us set up with JWT and my front end isn't set up for Auth yet?

Comment: Could be.  Do you get a 403 error if you try to go to http://localhost:3000/api/users/5743a5f9db9e7ce607d47c9c in a browser?

Comment: Oi no, but I get JSON data that says success: false  message: no token provided. I was about to start working on auth in the ionic version of this app so I wanted to make sure I can retrieve users. At least I know the back end is secure. Good news is that I can retrieve all of the users and their ids without a token, so I should be able to implement auth and make it work. At least it's not a mystery any more, thank you!

Comment: Ah, that's probably the problem then, no authorization.  I find the http status codes a little annoying.  403 (forbidden) is used to indicate an authorization problem and also forbidden operations.  Then authentication errors are typically returned as 401 (unauthorized).  Confusing.  Anyways, I'd try to pass a valid JWT with your request and see if that fixes this problem

Comment: As it turns out, .protect was called on a bunch of routes, and one of them happened to be the show one user route that I outlined above. So yeah, thanks for helping me get here!

Comment: You're welcome and I'm glad you got it figured out